# Python Flask Import file could not be resolved

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to import 'greek' to 'api' file in same directory

This is my directory

```
api
 |--pycache
 |--venv
 |--__init__.py
 |--api.py
 |--greek.py
```

If I used from greek import alphabet, it return

```
 from greek import alphabet  #Import "greek" could not be resolved
```

If I used from api.greek import alphabet, it return

```
 from api.greek import alphabet  #No module named 'api.greek'; 'api' is not a package
```

If I used from api import greek as NoCommandLine recommend, it return

```
 from api import greek  #ImportError: cannot import name 'greek' from partially initialized module 'api' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\liud7\Downloads\Option_cal\option_calculator\api\api.py)
```

Really lost, the link below is my code in imgur. Thank you in advance!

Update: Sorry for the confusion caused by the last post.

Update#2: Did what NoCommandLine said in the update response, although the import statement still show Import "greek" could not be resolved, it doesn't seem to affect the program. I could still call the function in the greek without any problem. Thank you all so much :)

Comment: Please post your code as text formatted as code using the little `{}` button in the editor instead of as a picture.

Comment: You say tried adding an *"-init-.py"* but what about the correctly named `__init__.py`?

Comment: Yes, I did and it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>If the parent folder is `api` and a child is `greek`, then what you need is</s>

1. An `__init__.py` file in the `api` folder
2. Then you can do `from api import greek` or `from api.greek import *`

Updating my response since original post has been updated and a directory structure (different from earlier post) provided

1. Based on your updated directory structure, I do not believe you need the `__init___.py`.
2. It seems you need a function or class called `alphabet` which is in `greek.py`. You should just do `import greek` and then to use `alphabet`, you do `greek.alphabet`

Comment: Hi I have try your method just now, but it return ImportError cannot import name from partially initialized module. Do you know what should I do?

Comment: Yep, that save it. In the import statement, it still show Import "greek" could not be resolved but I could access the method and call it. Very weird. Thank you very much